# Facebook Like button for website

Tags: php, facebook

Can anyone tell me how can i get the Facebook like button for my website and also a like button for individual product. What is the full process to get the like button.

Thanks for your help:)

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250
/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f34bbcf02602463"></script>
```

This is code i use to website like button, but it's not working.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Did you even try searching for it? Have a look through https://developers.facebook.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

It's an easy to use configurator to generate a like button, with any "URL to like" you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Facebook Developers site,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

With Facebook latest features you have to follow few steps.

1 Create an App for your site. And get the app ID. Lets say you get xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

2 Put this code just after the body tag of your HTML.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

3 And the n put bellow code with your URL's where you need the like button.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-href="<?php echo $yourURL ?>"></div>
```